# How to convert angular 1 directive in js to angular 2 atribute directive in TypeScript

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, typescript, angular, angular2-directives

I tried this from tutorials, but i don't know how to do it in this case. Please help me convert this to Angular 2 Atribute Directive.

```
function minimalizeBar($timeout) {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        template: '<a class="navbar-minimalize minimalize-styl-2 btn btn-    primary " href="" ng-click="minimalize()"><i class="fa fa-bars"></i></a>',
        controller: function ($scope, $element) {
            $scope.minimalize = function () {
                $("body").toggleClass("mini-navbar");
                if (!$('body').hasClass('mini-navbar') ||     $('body').hasClass('body-small')) {                        
                    $('#side-menu').hide();
                    setTimeout(
                        function () { 
                            $('#side-menu').fadeIn(500);
                        }, 100);
                } else if ($('body').hasClass('fixed-sidebar')){
                    $('#side-menu').hide();
                    setTimeout(
                        function () {
                            $('#side-menu').fadeIn(500);
                        }, 300);
                } else {
                    $('#side-menu').removeAttr('style');
                }
            }
        }
    };
};
angular
    .module('x') 
    .directive('minimalizeBar', minimalizeBar)
```

This code is from angularjs directives.